# Getting data from a Editext

Tags: android

I am fairly new to android development, I know there are already some answers on this topic already. Although each of the ones i have read I tried and not worked. The idea is simple, whatever data is inputted into the Edittext dialog it should appear on the main activity screen. Now, i have tried the whole value.getText() and value.getText().toString(); (Although shouldnt need to use the toString() as its already a string.)

Not sure what i am missing here :s

```
final Context context = this;
public EditText test;
RelativeLayout layout;
public EditText data;
String value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.add_item) {
        add_item();
        return true;
    } else if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void add_item() {

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View dialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            value = data.getText().toString();
                            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                            tv.setText(value);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            layout.addView(tv);
                            Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: If you use a debugger and step through the `onClick()` method, what does `value` contain after execution of this line of code: `value = data.getText().toString();`?

Answer (score 1):

The **Dialog as is own layout** which is inflated with `View dialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);` and setted with  `alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);`

Be sure that the EditText with id `dialog` is in the `dialog` layout and 
set `data (EditText)` after inflation like :

```
View dialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
data = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog);
```

Comment: I don't think that OP's `EditText` is in the `Dialog`. It looks like the `EditText` is in the `Activity` layout and he is just using the dialog to confirm adding the text to the `Activity` layout.

Comment: according to his `add_item` method, he is inflating a view to be used by the Dialog. Maybe he is missing the EditText in the `R.layout.dialog` but he definitvely saving the EditText in the data member on activity Create. I've updated answer to prevent him about this case

Comment: Yes, he is inflating a view to be used in the dialog. But this has nothing to with the problem. The view he is inflating in the dialog doesn't have any `EditText` in it. Anyway, OP found his problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I created the `final EditText data = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog);`it was pointing to the wrong id it should be pointing to the correct EditText id which should be `final EditText data = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);`

This fixed it.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as the my answer 3hours ago.